# How to scale down Area chart in ReCharts

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, jsx, recharts

I'm using the recharts library and my data has very large values because I'm taking covid infected numbers but my chart gets too big and I want to display it in the given area only
[image]

```
   <Box
  w="5xl"
  py={4}
  px={8}
  rounded="lg"
  bg={useColorModeValue("white", "gray.900")}
  shadow="lg"
>
  <Flex justify="center">
    <Select mb="1.5" width="47%" variant="filled" onChange={addOpt}>
      <option defaultValue>Choose an option</option>
      <option>Infected</option>
      <option>Recovered</option>
      <option>Deceased</option>
    </Select>
  </Flex>
  <div>
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={500}>
      <AreaChart data={chartdata.length > 1 ? chartdata : data}>
        <Area dataKey="ykey"/>
        <XAxis dataKey="data"/>
        <YAxis dataKey="ykey"/>
      </AreaChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  </div>
</Box>
```

**this is a small part of the data array**

```
[   "0",   {
    "ykey": "1766"   },   {
    "ykey": "1804"   },   {
    "ykey": "1854"   },   {
    "ykey": "1894"   },   {
    "ykey": "1932"   },   {
    "ykey": "1984"   },   {
    "ykey": "2060"   },   {
    "ykey": "2127"   },   {
    "ykey": "2204"   },   {
    "ykey": "2279"   },   {
    "ykey": "2422"   },   {
    "ykey": "2519"   },   {
    "ykey": "2589"   },   {
    "ykey": "2693"   },   {
    "ykey": "2758"   },   {
    "ykey": "2879"   },   {
    "ykey": "2980"   },   {
    "ykey": "3138"   },   {
    "ykey": "3254"   },   {
    "ykey": "3274"   },   {
    "ykey": "3387"   },   {
    "ykey": "3518"   },   {
    "ykey": "3631"   },   {
    "ykey": "3749"   }]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in my data, Recharts takes numbers and not strings but I was giving it strings